# Listview size adapt on items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have an issue with the design of a listview.

I would like to reduce the list when there are a few items but if I put wrap content it's on the middle of the screen.

How can I do ?

My list view :

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_location"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/searchView_location"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/searchView_location"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/searchView_location"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/searchView_location"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Constraint layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

Comment: "ListView" is taking the height of its parent "constraintlayout" please share listview's parent layout

Comment: change its height to wrap_content i.e contraintlayout

Comment: @xlu Thanks but same issue with android:layout_height="wrap_content" on the constraint layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ListView height

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Remove top constraint

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Comment: in this case, you need to remove just a top constraint. I updated my answer

Comment: @Rankov thanks it's working, but when the list is too big it goes beyond the screen, to avoid that I limited the list to 6 items but I guess there must be a better way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Change its parent height to wrap_content i.e contraintlayout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_layout_search"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```